# Remove information about a fork from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have recently forked one of my Bitbucket projects to create a different edition of the service contained. The project the fork originated from lives on and the fork will never be merged back to the original project.

[image: Bitbucket message about a fork being behind]

How can I remove the reference to the originating project so that I don't get offered to merge code back to this project in the Bitbucket UI.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a simpler answer, but you could:

1. Make sure you have an up-to-date local copy of the repository.
2. Delete the project on BitBucket.
3. Re-create the project with the same name
4. `git push` your local repository to the new project.

Now you have a project with the same repository history that has no link to the "parent" repository.

Comment: Notice that this will delete Wiki, issues, etc. Try to ask Support to switch, I know it works on GitHub.